# How to convert 4 digit floating point to 2 digit floating point

Tags: java, floating-point

Please tell me the code converting double variable value of floating digits in to only 2 floating points?

Comment: Have you looked at `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean, for example, turning 10.1234 to 10.12, then try to experiment on this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

...

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double num = 10.1234;
double newNum = Double.parseDouble(df.format(num));
System.out.println(newNum);
```

Comment: `double newNum = df.format(num);` won't work. `format()` returns a string representation. Revert to your last answer.

Comment: oops, my bad. I kinda rushed my edit. thanks. changed it so that s/he gets a double output :)

Answer (score -3):

Use Math.round - [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Comment: Math#round returns an integer. Not a floating point with reduced precision.

Comment: Well..I figured I would hint it and let OP take is from there...Math.round( x * 100.0 ) / 100.0;

Comment: Put that in your answer and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Not doing this for votes/karma :-)

Comment: @Fergus Nevertheless it is not favorable to leave answers incomplete - it will just increase the noise on this site.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for most values.